# login, signup page not found in wagtail

Tags: django-allauth, account

I correctly followed the django-allauth documentation, installed it in my django wagtail project  and made configurations or applied settings according to the guide and also added url(r'', include('allauth.urls')), to my urls.py but i couldn't access the allauth pages like login because got a page not found error. Am requesting for your help.

**This is my base.py **

```
enter codePROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',
    'blog',
    'book',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    
]

SITE_ID = 1


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=[
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

    ]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            #'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my.cnf')
            'read_default_file':"D:/wagproj/mysite/mysite/my.cnf"
            }
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



  
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# JavaScript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
# See 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "mysite"

# Search
# https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/backends.html
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
    }
}

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
 here
```

**this is my urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'', include('allauth.urls')),
    #path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    # Wagtail URLs
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

]
```

**This is the error i  recieved on trying to access the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/, i was redirected to the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/ and got this error below.

**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/
Raised by:  wagtail.core.views.serve
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

django-admin/
admin/
documents/
search/ [name='search']
signup/ [name='account_signup']
login/ [name='account_login']
logout/ [name='account_logout']
password/change/ [name='account_change_password']
password/set/ [name='account_set_password']
inactive/ [name='account_inactive']
email/ [name='account_email']
confirm-email/ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
password/reset/ [name='account_reset_password']
password/reset/done/ [name='account_reset_password_done']
^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
password/reset/key/done/ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
social/
google/
facebook/
facebook/login/token/ [name='facebook_login_by_token']
_util/authenticate_with_password/<int:page_view_restriction_id>/<int:page_id>/ [name='wagtailcore_authenticate_with_password']
_util/login/ [name='wagtailcore_login']
^((?:[\w\-]+/)*)$ [name='wagtail_serve']
The current path, account/, matched the last one.
```

Comment: I installed allauth with Wagtail 2.16.1 and it worked for me. Can you share the exact error you are getting? It may just be something small like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect to /profile might occur because you are already logged in (as admin in wagtail)